# How can I replace the CouchDB server for Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, couchdb, desktopcouch

I'm writing some applications and tools that are meant to make use of Ubuntu One, but since the CouchDB sync service has been down for months, I haven't been able to test it or demonstrate how it will work in practice. This is very limiting to me, so I would like to setup a temporary CouchDB service to replace Ubuntu Ones own.

But how do I do it? Obviously, if I just add an entry to /etc/hosts for couchdb.one.ubuntu.com, then I can make things connect to my service. But the user needs to be able to login etc. How do I accomplish those things? Is there anything special about the couchdb Ubuntu One uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CouchDB can sync to other servers

http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/replication.html

You can use futon ('web' interface)

http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/tour.html#replication

Your own futon address:

$HOME/.local/share/desktop-couch/couchdb.html

or

file:///home/{username}/.local/share/desktop-couch/couchdb.html